# ¿Cómo coloco una imagen debajo del nav en bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Uso **Bootstrap 4.1** y este es mi código:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary n1 col-12">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01"></div>  
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente agrega la imagen y colocala donde quieras.  Si la quieres a la derecha puedes usar `float: right`. Algo asi:

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary n1 col-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01"></div>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una de las formas en la que lo puedes hacer ahora si quieres que no se repita la imagen debes usar la funcion no-repeat y las funciones left, right o center si para alinear la imagen imagen

```css
nav {
 background: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random") fixed left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary n1 col-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01"></div>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```